# Modify folder permissions of parent directory that were automatically created by autofs

Tags: linux, centos, samba, cifs, autofs

I am currently following [this guide](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares) to setup CentOS 8 to automount samba shares.

I am aware that we can change autofs auto mounted folders permissions using

```
uid=...,gid=...,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770
```

and *it does technically work*...

Here's my current setup, so my `auto.master` contains the following

```
/mnt/smb /etc/auto.smb.top
```

`auto.smb.top`

```
* -fstype=autofs,-Dhost=& file:/etc/auto.smb.sub
```

`auto.smb.sub`

```
* -fstype=cifs,sec=ntlmv2,credentials=${HOME}/.${host}.smbpasswd,uid=${UID},gid=sambausers,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix ://${host}/&
```

with all the configuration above, `/mnt/smb/192.168.x.x /shared_folder` does have the expected permissions, however the permissions for its parent directories `/mnt/smb` and `/mnt/smb/192.168.x.x` are owned by `root` and does not follow the configuration from autofs.

I even tried to modify `/mnt` (which is not auto created by `autofs`)to the corresponding permissions but what happens is that the created `smb` folder still is owned by root and does not follow the permissions at all of its parent directory. Did I miss anything in my configuration? I tried adding `uid=...,gid=...,file_mode=...` to `autofs.smb.top`, but the same issue persists.

with the current setup described above autofs makes the following

- `/mnt/smb` - owned by `root`
- `/mnt/smb/192.168.x.x` - owned by `root`
- `/mnt/smb/192.168.x.x/shared_folder` - owned by `sambausers` (custom group I made)

but what I wanted was

- `/mnt/smb` - owned by `sambausers` with `0770`
- `/mnt/smb/192.168.x.x` - owned by `sambausers` with `0770`
- `/mnt/smb/192.168.x.x/shared_folder` - owned by `sambausers` with `0770`